# Find elements that sum to a given number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, subset-sum

I have to find the list of orders that have sum of order amount equal to or greater than a given number. For example,

```
order #  amount
o1        100
o2         50
o3         90
o4        150
o5        20
o6        30
o7        50
```

And if I need to find the orders in which sum of order amount is equal to 300 or greater than 300, then I should get o5, o6, o2, o7, o3,o1 or o1, o4, o3. It does not matter if order is min to max or max to min.  How can I do it in a minimal way? I know first step would be to sort. I can use array sum to get sum of all elements but how do I get the elements that add up to or are just greater than a given number?

I am using Ruby on Rails with Oracle as db.

Comment: What DB client you are using ? Mysql, Sqllite3 etc .. which one ?

Comment: I think something may be missing from your question. Since the amounts are all non-negative, you can simply include all the items. Either it will be sufficient or the goal cannot be achieved. I suspect you have specified a constraint  but not the objective. Do you want to find all combinations of orders that meet the requirement?

Comment: ...or perhaps the combination of orders with the fewest number of items?

Comment: Yes, combination of orders with the fewest number of items. I need to find the minimum number of orders that match the criteria and then cancel those as a result of a business rule.

Comment: Can you tell me how the both *is equal to 250 or greater than 300* is possible ?

Comment: Suppose I pick the combination of o1, o3, o4 and order total of 300 needs to be reverted, then I will have to cancel o1, o4 and update the amount of o3 from 90 to 40. So at the end of cancelling, I have cancelled the orders equal to amount 300. I can pick any order that is to cancel minimum amount orders first or maximum first. But at end, i should have cancelled orders equal to 300.

Comment: Get some idea from this -- http://aprogrammerwrites.eu/?p=635

Comment: How can I get the list of orders without using a complicated query at db level? The list of orders will not be very long mostly couple of hundreds. I want to avoid writing a complicated raw query. We use sqlite for local development and oracle for stage and prod env. Hence, I cannot write a query which does not work in a particular env. It would be better if I get a list of orders from db and then select the ones to cancel in my ruby method.

Comment: You should edit your question to incorporate your answer, "Yes, combination of orders with the fewest number of items...". Readers should not be expected to read through the comments to comprehend the question.

Comment: This is too broad. You need to post your attempted solution, not a list of requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually quite simple. First, order the orders by decreasing quantity:

```
orders = [["o1", 100], ["o2", 50], ["o3", 90], ["o4", 150],
          ["o5",  20], ["o6", 30], ["o7", 50]] 

sorted_orders = orders.sort_by(&:last).reverse
  #=> [["o4", 150], ["o1", 100], ["o3", 90], ["o7", 50],
  #    ["o2", 50],  ["o6", 30],  ["o5", 20]]
```

Suppose:

```
min_req = 300
```

First see if `min_req` can be achieved by using all the items:

```
orders.reduce(0) { |tot,(_,qty)| tot+qty } < min_req
  #=> false
```

Had this returned `true` we'd be finished: since the quantities are all non-negative, we would have computed the largest possible value for the sum of a subset of quantities.

Then simply take items in the sorted order until the quantities sum to at least `min_req`:

```
tot = 0
sorted_orders.take_while { |_,qty| tot < min_req && tot += qty }
  #=> [["o4", 150], ["o1", 100], ["o3", 90]]
```

We can wrap this in a method:

```
def smallest_combination(orders, min_req)
  return nil if orders.reduce(0) { |tot,(_,qty)| tot+qty } < min_req
  tot = 0
  orders.sort_by(&:last)
        .reverse
        .take_while { |_,qty| tot < min_req && tot += qty }
end

smallest_combination(orders, 300)
  #=> [["o4", 150], ["o1", 100], ["o3", 90]] 
smallest_combination(orders, 400)
  #=> [["o4", 150], ["o1", 100], ["o3", 90], ["o7", 50], ["o2", 50]] 
smallest_combination(orders, 500)
  #=> nil
```